# Count duplicate values in SQL Server and display as another column

Tags: sql-server, count

I need a query to obtain following result.
The aim is to count the repeated value of a column in A or B or C and put in column C.
Also the repeated rows should be truncated or not displayed.

> The difficulty is SQL Server takes date as both date and time. So distinct value of date cannot be separated from 'datetime'.

Column A is from one table(say TableA) and Column B is from another table(say TableB).

Table_1:
(Before using query)

```
Column_A  | Column_B |      Column_C
12345678  |  AB      | 2013-08-30 15:06:52.000
12345678  |  AB      | 2013-08-30 15:08:19.000
12345678  |  AB      | 2013-08-30 16:08:19.000
23456789  |  BC      | 2014-06-20 10:08:19.000
23456789  |  BC      | 2014-06-20 12:08:19.000
34567891  |  CD      | 2016-03-20 10:08:19.000
```

Table_1:
(After using query, the table should look like this below)

```
Column_A  | Column_B |      Column_C           | Column_D
12345678  |  AB      | 2013-08-30 00:00:00.000 | 3
23456789  |  BC      | 2014-06-20 00:00:00.000 | 2
34567891  |  CD      | 2016-03-20 00:00:00.000 | 1
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a Group by:

```
SELECT Column_A, Column_B, count(*) as Column_C
FROM Table_1
GROUP BY Column_A, Column_B
```